# Counting the number of elemnts in a stack

Tags: delphi

I am working with delphi.How do i get the total number of elements in a stack and retain the stack after the process.I am aware that this can also be achived by creating a temporary stack and copying  the original stack to the new one (temp),so as to then pop the elements from the temp while counting, but i am not allowed to use this formular. Can somebody help me with an algorthm that achieves my task please!

Comment: The stack will know what it holds. It's usually trivial to expose the element count. Nobody is going to give you details until you provide some.

Comment: What stack are you using? In modern Delphi versions there is a generic stack, [Generics.Collections.TStack](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Collections.TStack), with a `Count` property to get the number of elements in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the generic **TStack** collection class in *Delphi XE4* then the number of elements currently in the stack is already exposed directly via the **Count** property:

```
var
  myStack: TStack<Integer>;
begin
  myStack := TStack<Integer>.Create;
  myStack.Push(42);

  ShowMessageFmt('Stack contains %d elements', [myStack.Count]);      

  myStack.Free;
end;
```

However, since you presumably have not found this property then it is possible you are using some other stack implementation.

Determining how best to access the same information about the stack from the implementation you are using is impossible without further details about that particular implementation.